# How to prove $\rho(A^{-1}N)=\rho(A^{-1})\rho(N)$?

Tags: spectral-theory

it is known that if $A=M-N$ is a regular splitting of the matrix $A$ and $A^{-1}\geq 0$, then 
$$\rho(M^{-1}N)=\frac{\rho(A^{-1}N)}{1+\rho(A^{-1}N)}.$$

And if $AN=NA$, it holds 
$$\rho(M^{-1}N)=\frac{\rho(A^{-1})\rho(N)}{1+\rho(A^{-1})\rho(N)}.$$ 
I wonder how to prove this equality.
It is known that if $AN=NA$, then $\rho(AN)\leq \rho(A)\rho(N)$. So I guess that because of the special relationship of $A$ and $N$, so $\rho(AN)=\rho(A)\rho(N)$. Am I right? Or is there  is anyone who can help to prove the second equatlity?

Comment: Please clarify: is $\rho$ spectral radius?

Comment: Yes, $\rho$ is the spectral radius.